# Adding 24 hours to NSDate

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to add 24 hours to the current date and then save in Parse. I literally just did this and it was working, but I think I tweaked something and broke it because now the future time stores in Parse as the current time.

Here is my code:

```
let futureTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(NSCalendarUnit.Hour, value: 24, toDate: NSDate(), options: NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents)
myObject.setObject(futureTime!, forKey: "futureTime")
```

ANSWER:

just had to switch the unit to .Day instead of .Hour and add "1" instead of "24". Not sure why 24 wouldn't work though.

Comment: have you tried adding a day instead of 24 hours? Just a general advice, no idea if it solves your problem at all

Comment: Just tried and it worked thanks!

Comment: @cb428 just pass an empty array for options [ ]

Comment: The problem is that you've used the `WrapComponents` option, which specifically tells the calendar **not** not increment the day when the hour wraps around. But it is better to add one day rather than 24 hours, since adding 24 hours will probably give you an unexpected answer on the days when daylight saving time activates or deactivates.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of adding 24 hours, add the equivalent 1 day:

```
let futureTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Day, value: 1, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

Or - to fix the actual problem, remove the options

```
let futureTime = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit.Hour, value: 24, toDate: NSDate(), options: [])
```

Additionally you can remove the `NSCalendarUnit` in the `NSCalendarUnit.Hour`

Comment: Note that adding 24 hours may give an unexpected answer on the days when daylight saving time activates or deactivates.

Comment: @robmayoff hmm, you might be right about that one - will adding one day "solve" that issue though? WIll the time really stay the same and only the day be increased - meaning the time will either be 25 or 23 hours in the future?

Comment: Today 7am plus 1 day = Tomorrow 7am. May be 24, 25 or 23 hours in the future, Today 7am plus 24 hours = Tomorrow, 7am or 6am or 8am, but always 24 hours in the future.

Comment: @gnasher729 okay, if that is how they internally work, thank you both for clarification

Answer (score 0):

This adds a day onto a date:

```
let components: NSDateComponents = NSDateComponents()
components.setValue(1, forComponent: NSCalendarUnit.Day);

let date: NSDate = NSDate()
let tomorrowDate = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingComponents(components, toDate: date, options: NSCalendarOptions(rawValue: 0))
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

It won't work when you are specifying `options` as `NSCalendarOptions.WrapComponents`. Specify just `NSCalendarOptions()` instead.

When `.WrapComponents` is specified, then overflow in a unit doesn't get carried into higher units. That means that changing hours won't change any other components.

Adding 1 day instead of 24 hours will work for most cases but it's not a real fix. You will have exactly the same problem when you use that code on December 30 - the change in days won't get carried into years. You have to fix the `options`.

Comment: Could the downvoter please comment what's wrong with my answer?